# Authentification model laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I changed my authentication model to Admin instead of the default model User. The authentication works fine. when i use this method `Auth::admin()->id;` I get this error :

> method admin does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed the model, but the auth functions will still remain the same for any model.

So you should just use `Auth::user()->id` or even better, `Auth::id()`.
And these will work perfectly fine with your admin model.

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this answer as the solution so other users might find this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the model in `app/config/auth.php` from User to your Admin model path?

Comment: Yes, OP said so in his question.